# split screen focussing: 4 vs 6 degree circle

Tags: mamiya

I'm finding getting really sharp focus increasingly difficult with my RB67 and C330 cameras. Mamiya made split screen focussing screens for both, but they come in 4 degree and 6 degree versions. What's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

The split image rangefinder in the 6 degree version is supposed to be more sensitive (that is the same amount of defocusing will make the two sides of the split image further apart), but doesn't work well with lenses longer than about 180mm in focal length. The 4 degree version is a little less sensitive but works better with the longer lenses.